# Creating an asp.net table with cell onclick attribute

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am creating an asp.net table in code behind. Certain cells has an onclick attribute which fires a modal popup, the cell that has the onclick attribute also has data in the cell which I want to get to get and put into a label in the modal popup.

This is code behind

```
 Table1.Rows(i).Cells(y).Text = "For" & "<br />" & info(x).RoomFor.Trim & "<br />" & "Tel" & "<br />" & info(x).RoomPhone.Trim 
 Table1.Rows(i).Cells(y).Attributes.Add("onclick", "ShowSuccess();")
 Table1.Rows(i).Cells(y).Attributes.CssStyle.Add("cursor", "pointer")
```

this is in the aspx page

```
function ShowSuccess() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(0)").text();
    alert(tr);
    $('#Text1').val('Wombat'); testing purposes
    $('#Lbl1').text('Wombat'); testing purposes
    $("#mySuccess").modal("show");
}
```

the table is being created OK and the click event works and a popup occurs but I am unable to get any of the data from the cell. What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Can you edit your post add your markup for your grid as well as the full code for the OnClick handler? More code and context is always better than less!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me, it would be far better to pull data from the database, and fill out a grid. Then for each row of the grid, you have say a "view" button, and that view button would then display/popup the details of that one row?

So, we need two parts:

our "table display" - a gridview is a great choice.

Then we need the "controls and markup" that defines the popup.

Then we need to adopt some kind of popup system. I suggest using jQuery.UI.

Since most default templates for webforms ALREADY includes jQuery, then it is a simple matter to have/adopt/add/enjoy jQuery.UI.

So, first up, lets build the GridView to display - say in this case a list of hotels.

So, this markup:

```
<div id="MyGridArea" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        DataKeyNames="ID"
        CssClass="table table-hover" Width="60em" GridLines="None"
        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="cmdEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CssClass="btn myshadow"
                        OnClick="cmdEdit_Click" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="cmdAdd" runat="server" Text="+Add new"  CssClass="btn myshadow"/>
</div>
```

And then our code to load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName"
    GridView1.DataSource = Myrst(strSQL)
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And now we have this:

[image]

So, next part/question?

Do you really need a full row click, or will the above example with a button suffice?

with above, it quite nice, since if you look close, the button in the GV is a simple plain jane button click.

So, the button click code is this:

```
Protected Sub cmdEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As Button = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.NamingContainer
    Dim intPK As Integer = GridView1.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item("ID")

    Dim strSQL As String =
        $"SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = {intPK}"
    fLoader(MyEditArea, Myrst(strSQL).Rows(0))
    ViewState("PK") = intPK     ' same our PK for later

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType, "popedit", $"popedit('{btn.ClientID}')", True)

End Sub
```

Note VERY close how we grab/get the current grid row click. However, what we REALLY want/need is to get the database row PK id. And note how we did not have to include/show/display the PK "id" in the client side markup, or GV. (that is what the datakeys feature does).

the other few lines of code simple "loads up" a bunch of controls in a "div", that we can THEN popup.

So, the markup is just a bunch of controls. It looks like this:

```
<div id="MyEditArea" runat="server" 
style="float: left; display: none;padding:15px;border-style:solid" >
<div style="float: left" class="iForm">

    <label>HotelName</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server" f="HotelName" Width="280" /> <br />
    <label>First Name</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tFN" runat="server" f="FirstName" Width="140" /> <br />
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tLN" runat="server" f="LastName" Width="140" /><br />

    <label>City</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tCity" runat="server" f="City" Width="140" /><br />
    <label>Province</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tProvince" runat="server" f="Province" Width="75" />
</div>

<div style="float: left; margin-left: 20px" class="iForm">
    <div style="float: left">
        <label>Description</label>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server" Width="290px" TextMode="MultiLine"
            Height="100px" f="Description"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>

    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 14px">
        <label>Hotel Options</label>
        <br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSmoking" runat="server" Text="Smoking" f="Smoking" /><br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBalcony" runat="server" Text="Balcony" f="Balcony" /><br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBags" runat="server" Text="Has Baggage" f="HasBaggage" /><br />
    </div>

    <div style="clear: both">
    </div>

    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" f="Active" Text=" Active"
        runat="server" TextAlign="Right" Width="171px" />

</div>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
<hr />

<button id="cmdSave" runat="server" class="btn myshadow" type="button"
    onserverclick="cmdSave_ServerClick" >
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved">Save</span>
</button>

<button id="cmdCancel" runat="server" class="btn myshadow" style="margin-left: 15px"
    type="button"
    onclick="myclose();return false" >
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left">Back/Cancel</span>
</button>

<button id="cmdDelete" runat="server" class="btn myshadow" style="margin-left: 15px"
    type="button"
    onserverclick="cmdDelete_ServerClick"
    onclick="if (!confirm('Delete this record?')) {return false};">
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">Delete</span>
</button>
<br />
<br />
</div>
```

I really did not have to post the above.

but, the jQuery.UI dialog? That is the "magic" part, and jQuery.UI can turn any div area into a pop dialog. So, I have this jQuery.UI dialog code:

```
<script>
    function popedit(btnS) {
        var btn = $('#'+ btnS)
        var myDialog = $("#MyEditArea");
        myDialog.dialog({
            title: "Edit Hotel",
            width: "45%",
            modal: true,
            appendTo: "form",
            dialogClass: "dialogWithDropShadow",
            close: myclose,
            position: { my: "right top", at: "right bottom", of: btn }
        });
    }

    function myclose() {
        var myDialog = $("#MyEditArea");
        myDialog.dialog('close')
        if (myDialog.hasClass('ui-dialog-content')) {
            myDialog.dialog('destroy');
        }
    }
</script>
```

And the result is now this:

[image]

Now, I suppose we could add a full row click anywhere, and it is possible to add a click to JUST one of the cells, and get a value back, but it not clear if the goal is really to get JUST the grid row, take action as above shows, or actually have a cell click.

If you need a actual cell click example (say based on the above grid), then just ask - I'll post some code on how to achieve that idea if you wish.